# Reading certain columns from multiple data files into one file in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have about 30 data files and I need to extract the 4th, 5th, and 6th columns. Then skip 14 columns and grab the next 3 columns and so on till the end of the file. Each data file is about 400 rows and 17000 columns. So far I have this:

```
file_list = glob.glob('*.dat')

with open("result.dat", "wb") as outfile:
    for f in file_list:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write(infile.read())

data = np.loadtxt('result.dat')

arr = np.array(data)
a = arr[:, 4:-1:17]
b = arr[:, 5:-1:17]
c = arr[:, 6:-1:17]
```

This is writing a file called result.dat that contains all of the data from the multiple files and then I extract the columns I need.  However, this is taking a long time to create the array because it is writing all of the information that I do not need as well. Is there a way to only read in the specific columns I am interested instead into the result.dat file?  This should cut down the time significantly.

Comment: Is creating `result.dat` slow, or just reading it?  Experiment with the `usecolumns` parameter of `loadtxt`.  `loadtxt` also reads the file one line at a time, splits it, collects columns, saves it all in a list of lists.  At the end it turns everything into an array.

Comment: The creation of the result.dat is slow.

Answer (score 1):

`numpy.loadtxt` is a pure python implementation, which makes is somehow slow.
Using `pandas.read_csv()` is way faster. You also do not need to write another file with the complete content (if you do not need this file for other purposes).

This is equivalent code using `pandas.read_csv`:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

file_list = glob.glob('*.dat')
cols = [4, 21, 38] # add more columns here

df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in file_list:
    df = df.append(
        pd.read_csv(f, delimiter='\s+', header=None, usecols=cols),
        ignore_index=True,    
    )

arr = df.values
```

The equivalent numpy code would be:

```
import glob
import numpy as np

file_list = glob.glob('*.dat')
cols = [0, 1, 2]  # add more columns here

data = []
for f in file_list:
    data.append(np.loadtxt(f, usecols=cols))

arr = np.vstack(data)
```

If timed both with 10 files of random numbers with shape (10000, 10).

pandas solution:
0.95 s

numpy solution:
2.6 s

Comment: Do you know of a different way to get the columns that I am interested in instead of designating cols equal to all of the columns because it goes up to 17,000 columns in one data file.  I did try this method just for the first couple of columns and it did work!

Comment: you could use some of numpys array factorys, for example `np.arange(4, 18000, 17)` will give you every 17th column from 4 to 18000

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy.loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) function accepts an optional `usecols` parameter.

You can generate column indices via:

```
usecols=set(xrange(4, num_col, 17)) | set(xrange(5, num_col, 17)) | set(xrange(6, num_col, 17))
```

Answer (score 0):

`loadtxt` takes any iterable, including a generator.  You could iterate through the files, but feed them directly to `loadtxt` rather than write an intermediate file.  No guarantee that it will save much time, but it may be worth the experiment.

Here's my test:

```
def foo(filelist):
    for name in filelist:
        with open(name) as f:
            for line in f:
                yield line
```

A simple test file

```
In [71]: cat urls.txt
one.com
two.url
three.four
```

Read it 2 times with `foo`:

```
In [72]: list(foo(['urls.txt','urls.txt']))
Out[72]: 
['one.com\n',
 'two.url\n',
 'three.four\n',
 'one.com\n',
 'two.url\n',
 'three.four\n']
```

use it in `loadtxt`:

```
In [73]: np.loadtxt(foo(['urls.txt','urls.txt']),dtype=str,delimiter='.',usecols=[1])
Out[73]: 
array(['com', 'url', 'four', 'com', 'url', 'four'], 
      dtype='|S4')
```

The other approach is to load each file, collect the arrays in a list, and concatenate them.

Your 'usecols' with 'use 3 skip 14' is a little awkward to construct.  Using 3 slices as you do is a nice idea, but you don't want to do that with `loadtxt`.

`np.r_` might make the task easier:

```
In [81]: np.r_[4:100:17, 5:100:17, 6:100:17]
Out[81]: 
array([ 4, 21, 38, 55, 72, 89,  5, 22, 39, 56, 73, 90,  6, 23, 40, 57, 74,
       91])

In [82]: np.sort(np.r_[4:100:17, 5:100:17, 6:100:17])
Out[82]: 
array([ 4,  5,  6, 21, 22, 23, 38, 39, 40, 55, 56, 57, 72, 73, 74, 89, 90,
       91])
```

`usecols` does not have to be sorted, so you could use either.